# PsExec why don't I get full output of remote command

Tags: c#, psexec

Why do I NOT get 3 lines of output from running TestApp remotely? In string 'output' I get license info plus "Start@" line, BUT not the next two lines:

```
    public static string RunPsExec()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Vence\Downloads\PSTools\PsExec.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\10.215.yy.yy -u xxxxxx -p ""xxxxxx"" C:\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe";
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string errormessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        p.WaitForExit();

        return output;
    }
```

TestApp:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start@ " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Middle@ " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("End@ " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    }
```

Comment: Side note: In my experience, most of the PsExec output is found in the `StandardError`, not the `StandardOutput`, for some reason.

Comment: Problem disappears when p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput is set to false

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I see is set RedirectStandardInput to false, since it is not needed in this example. 
However, if you would like to pass the input to the TestApp in a future (which requires RedirectStandardInput=true), one solution might be to use PAexec (https://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/) as an alternative to PsExec. According to these question ([Can't receive asynchronous output from psexec when launching application remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280413/cant-receive-asynchronous-output-from-psexec-when-launching-application-remotel)), PAExec writes directly to console buffer, instead of stout/sterr. To make it work, you would have to read the output asynchronously, like this:

```
public static string RunPsExec()
{

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\<path_to>\PaExec.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = @\\10.215.yy.yy -u xxxxxx -p ""xxxxxx"" ""C:\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe"" ";
    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Display(args.Data);

    p.Start();

    p.BeginOutputReadLine();

    p.WaitForExit(10000);

    return;


}

static void Display(string output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(output);

}
```